# DNN model suddenly not converging (having low loss and not changing much)

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

This is my code below.
I worked with the exact same model and it converged well when I didn't scaled the data.
The loss started somewhere around 1.0 and went down to 0.45.
However, after rewriting my code the model loss is bit weird. It starts from 0.4 and not converging. I'm wondering if I introduced any errors in the code while rewriting my code. Can someone please help me where I did it wrong??

```
label = np.array(df['label'])
features = np.array(df.iloc[:, 0:8])

X_train, X_rem, y_train, y_rem = train_test_split(features, label, test_size=0.3, random_state=seed)
X_val, X_test, y_val, y_test = train_test_split(X_rem, y_rem, test_size=0.5, random_state=seed)

scaler = StandardScaler().fit(X_train)
X_train = scaler.transform(X_train)
X_val = scaler.transform(X_val)
X_test = scaler.transform(X_test)


def DNN():
    input_layer = Input(shape=(8,), name='input_layer')
    Dense_1 = Dense(64, activation = 'relu', kernel_initializer = HeUniform(seed =1))(input_layer)
    Dense_2 = Dense(32, activation = 'relu', kernel_initializer = HeUniform(seed =1))(Dense_1)
    output_layer = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', kernel_initializer = GlorotUniform(seed =1))(Dense_2)
    model = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=output_layer)
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.001),  metrics=['acc', 'Recall', 'AUC'])
    return model

model = DNN()

my_callbacks = [
    EarlyStopping(patience=10),
    ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor="val_loss", factor=0.3, patience= 5, cooldown = 3, mode="min", min_lr=0.0001, verbose =1),
    ModelCheckpoint(monitor="val_loss", save_best_only = True, filepath = './checkpoint'),
    TensorBoard(log_dir='./logs')
    ]

history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=64, epochs=150, validation_data=(X_val, y_val), callbacks=my_callbacks)
```

This outputs:
[image]

Comment: Honestly speaking I didn't find any bugs. Have you done some experiments on it like changing the model architecture, Changing the batch_size, etc.?

Comment: It seemed to me that you are not restarting your model so your model starts from the last saved weights. Therefore your model doesn't improve. In other words, your model gets stuck in the local minima. (As I see)

Comment: @HakanAkgün I restarted the kernel and reran the model. Is it not enough to avoid starting from the last saved weights??

Comment: @AbhishekPrajapat yes I tried chaning batch_size, different kernel initialization, and learning rate. It seems like rescaling makes the result bit weird. The model loss ends up in a similar place at the end for both scaled and unscaled data. But the scaled version's loss doesn't go below from where it started whereas unscaled version starts from higher loss point but manages to go down.

Comment: It could be the nature of the data. If you scale it you lose information from your datasets.

Comment: @dkdlfls26 yes actually it's enough, now I couldn't remember why  I've written that. I'll tell you when I remember.